# Django use Admin Template

Tags: python-3.x, django-templates, django-admin

I created the following simple template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> .... </head>
<body>
<h1>Harvester: {{ harvester_name }} </h1>
 <textarea rows="10" cols="50">
 {{ log_text }}
 </textarea>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Created in the path `myProject/myApp/templates/myApp`
Now I would like to use the admin template for my template.
So that I have the header similar to the one used in the change_form.
As seen in the image.
[image: Admin Heade]

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your template, at top. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template)

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block content %}
    Your stuff here
{% endblock %}
```